# ObjectAnchorsWorldManager.cs error : type or namespace name WindowsMR does not exist in the namespace UnityEngine.XR

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, unity-xr

I'm following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-03) from Microsoft in order to create a multi-users experience in augmented reality between an Hololens and an Android app.

After installing the following packages :

- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.MultiUserCapabilities.2.7.2.unitypackage
- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.7.2.unitypackage
- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2.unitypackage

and following the tutorial, I can launch the app in the Unity Editor with no issue and I can see a message indicating "number of players in the experience: 1".

**The problem**
When I try to build the app in order to launch it on the Hololens, I get the following error which cause the build to fail :

```
Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.azure.object-anchors.runtime@f40a6f902078-1669719345205\Runtime\Core\ObjectAnchorsWorldManager.cs(151,29): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WindowsMR' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

**What I've tried**
I tried to re-import the XR Plug-in
[image]
[image]

I use Unity 2019.4.36f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I already mentioned in your last thread that this sample should run on **Unity 2020 LTS + Open XR**. And both the [Azure Spatial Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-new-unity-hololens-app?tabs=azure-portal) used in this sample and the [Azure Object Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/object-anchors/quickstarts/new-unity-hololens-app) you are using are recommended to use **Unity 2020.3 LTS + Open XR**.

For this error message, it requires the [Windows XR Plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.windowsmr@2.0/manual/index.html), but this project was not created with this, so a series of error messages may appear when importing this package. It is still recommended that you use **Unity 2020.3 LTS** and **Open XR** for development.

Comment: But it isn't possible to develop for Hololens 1 using Unity 2020.3 so after working around I still can't make it work

Comment: This sample was developed for HoloLens 2 and does not apply to HoloLens 1.

Comment: Yes I'll try using Azure Spatial Anchor which seems to be compatible with HoloLens 1. Thanks !